# Initialization completed event in QT4 GUI

Tags: python, qt4

I have a QT4 and python 2.4 based GUI. The user starts using it by opening a file. In addition to explicit browsing, I would like to allow the user to specify a file to open as a command line argument. I am looking for some event in the QMainWindow (or wherever) that would allow me to detect when the application completed its initialization and is ready for user interaction at which point I could automatically open the file and populate the widgets. So far I could not find anything better than overriding showEvent which is not exactly it because the main window is still not visible at this point. It might be okay but I am looking for a proper way to do this. In some other UI toolkits that I have used in the past that would be something like “main form layout completed” event that would signal that the UI is safe to deal with.  Is there something similar in QT4? I am running this on Linux if that matters.

You insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an event here. It is guaranteed that everything is loaded after `__init__()` and `show()` have run, so you can just put your code for the file opening after that.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.show()
        # normal __init__ done

        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
                # do stuff with file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```